# How to search business in particular city using Geoapi in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, geoapi

Can anyone help me how to get list of business available in particular city using Geoapi.Is it possible to retrieve list of business using particular city in GeoApi. If it is possible please let me know how to do that with sample mql query or url link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can retrieve list of business around your location, your query will be as follows,

**MQL query:** `{"lat": 37.75629, "lon": -122.4213, "radius": "1km", "entity": [{"type": "business", "guid": null}]}`

**GeoAPI url query:** 
  http://api.geoapi.com/v1/q?q=%7B%22lat%22%3A+37.75629%2C+%22lon%22%3A+-122.4213%2C+%22radius%22%3A+%221km%22%2C+%22entity%22%3A+%5B%7B%22type%22%3A+%22business%22%2C+%22guid%22%3A+null%7D%5D%7D&apikey=demo&pretty=1

Here is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/geo-api/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fdemos%2Fwnm)

To get a feel for how GeoAPI works, here are some basic queries. Put the query in browser to see its JSON-formatted result.

```
* Search from a latitude, longitude coordinate pair:
      o http://api.geoapi.com/v1/search?lat=37.75647&lon=-122.421218&radius=0.1km&apikey=demo&pretty=1
* Get the parent entities of a lat, lon pair:
      o http://api.geoapi.com/v1/parents?lat=37.563475&lon=-122.323219&apikey=demo&pretty=1
* Get an entitys parents (in this case, the entity is Ritual Roasters in San Francisco, and its parents are the neighborhood and city its located in):
      o http://api.geoapi.com/v1/e/ritual-coffee-roasters-san-francisco-ca-94110/parents?apikey=demo&pretty=1
* Get information about a business (in this case, Ritual Roasters in San Francisco):
      o http://api.geoapi.com/v1/e/ritual-coffee-roasters-san-francisco-ca-94110/view/listing?apikey=demo&pretty=1
* Get information about an entity (in this case, San Francisco):
      o http://api.geoapi.com/v1/e/san-francisco-ca?apikey=demo&pretty=1
```